# Jenkins command in Execute shell cannot read environment variables from /etc/profile.d/xx.sh

Tags: jenkins

When I execute a shell script in Jenkins Execute shell build step, the pre-defined environment variables in `/etc/profile.d/xx.sh` does not work.

I need help! Thx!

Comment: Did you restart your Jenkins after adapting the `profile.d/*.sh`s?

Comment: Are you sure it is the same user? how do you connect to the slave?

Comment: Yes,I did.@GeroldBroser

Comment: It does not connect other slave, just a jenkins built step, the output of 'whoami' is 'jenkins' in the build step.@Tizkiko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash reads the profile *only* for interactive login shells, or if it is started with the `--login` option. It will not be read when performing a build step or when connecting a slave.

The easiest workaround will be to explicitly source the profile by adding a

```
. /etc/profile
```

in the beginning of your build step.

This will then also immediately reflect any changes, without need to restart the master or to reconnect the slave (depending on where the build is running).